# Print actual value of int when passed to a function that accepts a char parameter

Tags: c, char, int

I have a function `PutChar(int, int, char)` that prints out a given char at a given row and column. This function works fine if I pass it a char. I would also like to be able to pass an int between the range of 0-9 to the function and have it print the actual int value. For example, I would like for the following code to print the actual value of the int x :

```
int x = 5;
PutChar(1, 1, x);

void PutChar(int row, int col, char ch) {
    char str[20];

    sprintf(str, "\e[%d;%dH", row, col); // move cursor to row-col
    write(1, str, strlen(str)); 
    write(1, &ch, 1);
}
```

I have tried casting to a char when passing the int to the function, but it prints out strange characters.

**EDIT:** The range of ints that can be printed are 0-9. This is a homework assignment so I cannot change the prototype of the function.

Comment: Are you supposed to modify `PutChar` or use it as is to output 1 digit integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are supposed to use the `PutChar()` function to output single digit numbers, it is easy to convert those to a `char` with the appropriate value by adding `'0'`, as suggested by Shan:

```
PutChar(1, 1, x + '0');
```

If you are supposed to modify the `PutChar()` function to output digits when passed small integers, that can be done too.

Assuming your terminal supports ASCII or some encoding based on ASCII such as Latin1 or UTF-8, characters below 32 (space) are control characters.  It would not make much sense to *put* them on the screen at a given position.  You can therefore modify `PutChar()` to handle `char` values between `0` and `9` specifically, without conflicting with current behaviour on actual ASCII characters 32 and above (or even negative if `char` is signed):

```
void PutChar(int row, int col, char ch) {
    char str[20];

    sprintf(str, "\e[%d;%dH", row, col); // move cursor to row-col
    write(1, str, strlen(str));
    if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)
        ch += '0';  // convert small integer to digit
    write(1, &ch, 1);
}

void Test(void) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        PutChar(x + 1, x + 1, x);
    }
}
```

Also note that your program is unsafe: `sprintf` will cause a buffer overflow for large values of `row` and `col`.  You should use `snprintf()` and a larger buffer.  You can further simplify the code and call `write` just once:

```
void PutChar(int row, int col, char ch) {
    char str[46];
    int len;

    if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)
        ch += '0';  // convert small integer to digit
    len = snprintf(str, sizeof str, "\e[%d;%dH%c", row, col, ch);
    if (len > 0)
        write(1, str, len);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. For extra points and more reliability one could also catch control characters (c<32) and those >126 and print symbolic representations for them rather than letting them mess up the output or, worse, the terminal.

Comment: @Peter Schneider: good point for characters between 0 and 31, and possibly 127.  Characters below 0 or above 127 would be perfectly OK on a Latin1 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to achieve this. There, you can use either

- `%c` to print the `char` value
- `%d` to print the `int` value.

However, you need to change the logic to include a *flag* to indicate either of the cases.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it by using the same prototype for the function. The professor wants us to use that prototype. The range of ints that can be passed to that function is 0-9. Is there something I can do at the function call?

Comment: @Shan yes that can be done, but how you are going to decide whether you want the `char` representation or `int` representation? BTW, without changing the function prototype, for a single-threaded program, you can use a _global_ flag variable to achieve the same.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: you are sending the OP on a wrong track.  The spec is clear: if the `char` argument is in the range 0-9, print the digit, else print the char.

Comment: @chqrlie No, IMHO, what you're saying is not at all what OP mentioned, At very least, i'lll say it's not clear.

Comment: @chqrlie And even from your perspective, the _value_ itself can be used as the _flag_, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *the value itself can be used as the flag*.  The value of `ch` determines the behaviour of the function.  Unless the OP is not telling us the whole story.  @Shan: Are you supposed to modify `PutChar` or use it as it to output 1 digit integers?

Comment: @chqrlie I meant that the _value_ of the third argument can be used to determine whether to output a `char` or `int`. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: The OP says the function `PutChar()` prototype cannot be changed.  What is wrong with testing the value of `ch` to output a digit or a character?

Comment: @chqrlie I think you did not read my comment properly. :-) what is represented by  `value of the third argument`, in my previous comment? We're both telling the same story sir. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it doesn't look like a good idea to let a `PutChar()` function print something else than a char.

If you need to print an int, write a function `PutInt()` that does exactly that. You might need another function `PutString()` to achieve that.

Once you are finished, you've likely rewritten large parts of the standard library...

Comment: It way be a bad idea, but it is the assignment.  It is easy enough for the OP should produce working code... whether he wants to confront the teacher on the correctness of the question is a different matter.

Comment: that's new information that wasn't available originally. And I just can't believe a teacher is suggesting a task that's just plain impossible. A `char` is a `char` and there is no way to pass an `int` through that parameter without breaking the rules.

Comment: Of course there is! This is not `java` nor `C++`. No rules are broken: an `int` passed to `PutChar()` is converted to type `char`.  `PutChar()` semantics can be altered to output digits for values of `ch` in the range `0` to `9`.  It will be impossible to distinguish is `PutChar(row, col, 1);` from `PutChar(row, col, '\001');`, and `Putchar(row, col, 'A');` from `PutChar(row, col, 65);` but does it really matter?

Comment: a `char` is a `char`, not an `int`. The TO didn't ask on how to output the numerical value of a `char`, he asked about how to pass an `int` _through_ a `char` function parameter. And this is plain impossible.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, it is possible and here is an example: `Putchar(row, col, 'A')`. In `C`, `char` is an integer type. Conversion between `char` and `int` types is automatic and transparent.  As a matter of fact, in the C language, `'A'` **is** a constant of type `int`.  Similarly, the `printf` argument for  the `"%c"` format is an `int`.  Of course the signedness of `char` may yield surprising results when non ASCII chars are converted to `int`, and large values of `int` do not fit in `char` types.This is different from `C++` where `sizeof('A') == 1`.

Comment: By definition, `char` is an (at least) eight-bit type while `int`is the "natural" integer type of the machine (in practice, this means both are different bit length on nearly all platforms). You are right that there are defined conversions available between both, but you just can't pass the "wider" type through the "narrorwer" function parameter and that was what (before lots of changes happened to it) the original post was asking.

Comment: OK, I never saw the OP's original posting without the range restriction to `0..9` for an `int` argument.  Without this range restriction or a similar one, it would be impossible to tell what `PutChar()` is supposed to do. I grant you that the original posting with `x=20;` was rather confused.

Comment: you can always have a look at the original post and it's editing history if you click on the "edited xxx min ago" link below it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of ints is 0-9, I can just add '0' to the argument that I am passing. For example:

```
int x = 5;
PutChar(1, 1, x + '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

If its practicable for you, you could use VA_ARGS in your PutChar implementation:

```
PutChar(int row, int col, char* formatString, ...) {
    sprintf(str, "\e[%d;%dH", row, col); // move cursor to row-col
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vprintf (format, args); // untested example
    va_end (args);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie I posted this answer before the OP stated that he can not change the function prototype. As he posted the source code for PutChar, I assumed that it is his own function which he can edit at will.

Answer (score 0):

before calling `PutChar()`, if an `int` in the range 0..9 is to be output, then add 0x30 to the character. If any other `char` is to be output then do not add the 0x30

Comment: You should use `'0'` instead of hard coding ASCII with `0x30`.